# Two fieldsets are not working with css

Tags: html, css, jsp

When I use just one fieldset covering all the fiels, it shows the whole form and when I use like given below it just displays upper fieldset.. lower one is not displaying.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<form action ="" method= "post" name= "testform" id="testform" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>
    <h1 class ="fs-title">Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h1>
    <p class="fs-title"><a href="http://localhost:8081/quickpay/webapi/myresource">Get All Accounts</a></p>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <input  placeholder="Firstname" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
    <input  placeholder="MiddleName" type="text" id="middleName" name="middleName" />
    <input  placeholder="LastName" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" />

    </fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <fieldset>      
    <input  placeholder="Address"  type="text" id="address" name="address" />
    <input  placeholder="Pincode"  type="text" id="pincode" name="pincode" />
    <input  placeholder="Phone" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
    <input  placeholder="Email" type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    <input  placeholder="Password" type="text" id="password" name="password" />
    <input  placeholder="Confirm Password" type="text" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" />
    <input  placeholder="Balance" type="text" id="balance" name="balance" />
    <input  placeholder="CardId"   type="text"  id="cardId" name="cardId" />
    <input  placeholder="PIN"   type="text"  id="pin" name="pin" />
    <p><input  type ="submit" id="add-account" value="Add user" class ="adduserbutton"></input></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";


body {
font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
#testform{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#testform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

/*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
#testform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}

#testform input, #testform textarea {

    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#testform .adduserbutton {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#testform .adduserbutton:hover, #testform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60,;
}

.fs-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

## what could be the problem here?

## UPDATE

**Worked!**
I set position:relative in fieldset and display:block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem here,

```
#testform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

/*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute; //<----Here
}
#testform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none; //<----Here
}
```

Even if you set

```
#testform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: block;
}
```

It will display the second `<fieldset>` but with `position: absolute;` second `<fieldset>` will overlap first `<fieldset>` and first `<fieldset>` remain hidden in background.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt4fuccu/)

Comment: You are right. I set position:relative and display:block and it worked!
Thanks for replying :D

Comment: Still my radio buttons are displaying in weird way.
Can you have a look at them and tell me why ?? 
I'm a newbie in this

Comment: because they are not in <fieldset>

Comment: Even if I put them in fieldset they appear same.
That's why I thought to put them outside the fieldset

Comment: i put the radio inside the `<label>` and add this css `#testform input[type="radio"] {
    width: inherit !important;
}`

Comment: unfortunatly the link you send is blocked in my country, but you can see the changes here in this fiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/qt4fuccu/

Comment: How awesome is that! You rock..I learned a lot
I know I'm asking much but one more question when I put it inside fieldset,  radio appears by side to lastname..
http://jsfiddle.net/qt4fuccu/ any headways for that?

Comment: add `<br>` after `<input  placeholder="LastName" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" />` and you are good

Comment: pro and friendly suggestion, stop writing your own css and start using bootstrap framework, may b it looks bit difficult in beginning but later it will do all the dirty work for you

Comment: how stupid question was mine.
And thank you so much for the suggestion, I surely will start learning and using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I misinterpreted your question, but you're hiding the second fieldset with:

```
#testform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
   display: none;
}
```

So removing that should make it appear.

Comment: Even If I remove this it will still overlap due to absolute positioning of fieldset and won't appear. as @Shehary mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from your CSS.

//CSS

```
#testform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
   display: none;
}
```

note: also your input tags should follow this format:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
```

You have a `</input>` and `</>` for almost all of them.